Faster numpy calculations than reshaping with einsum
Consider the following in Python: A has dimension (T,), U has dimension (L,T) and G has dimension (K,T), Y is (L,L,T). My code outputs a numer1 and numer2 with dimensions (T, LK, 1), . Consider that numer1 is (T, LK, 1), while numer3 is (LK,1)
# MWE
np.random.seed(0)
T=250
K = 15
L = 20
A = np.random.normal(size=(T))
Y = np.random.normal(size=(L,L,T))
G = np.random.normal(size=(K,T))
U = np.random.normal(size=(L,T))

# Calculations
L, T = U.shape
K = G.shape[0]
Y_transposed = Y.transpose(2, 0, 1)
sG = np.einsum('it,jt->tij', G, G)
A_transposed = A[None, :, None].transpose(1, 0, 2)
numer1 = np.einsum('ai,ak->aik', U.T, G.T).reshape(T, L * K, 1)
numer2 = numer1 * A_transposed
numer3 = numer2.sum(axis=0)

It turns out that np.reshape is very slow in this piece of code. When I say slow, in mean it compared to other solutions that are loop-based. Is there a way to avoid reshaping by using the einsum in a different way since I take sums in the last step?
A similar approach would also benefit the other piece of code, for which the problem seems a bit more biting:
denom1 = np.einsum('aij,akl->aikjl', Y_transposed, sG).reshape(T, L * K, L *K)
denom2 = denom1 * A_transposed
denom3 = denom2.sum(axis=0)



First thing first, reshape is very fast when there is no copy involved. A copy is needed when no view can be created (typically due to transpositions). Moreover, Numpy transpositions are far from being optimal. Besides, Numpy is not fast when he last axis is small (e.g. 1) since it (generally) cannot use SIMD units in this case. Also note that you can use optimize=True or even optimize="geedy" for better performance on np.einsum (optimizations are disabled by default).

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so we can help you further?

In a small example, np.einsum('ai,ak->aik', U.T, G.T).reshape(T, L * K, 1), the reshape makes a view.  Its base is the einsum() result.  For a (3,4,5) aik array, the reshape only adds 2 µs  to 13.1 µs einsum.  Without timings on a samle calculation, I don't see what you are complaining about.

@JérômeRichard added the MWE. Using optimize in np.einsum turns out to slow down the calculation time in my example, but thanks for the hint

In your example, I got a 40 µs time for the first np.einsum + reshape which is very small. This is why optimize=True is slower (it introduce an overhead at startup so to speed up intensive computation but this one is not intensive). reshape takes only 2 µs on my machine so it is not a problem. In the second case, it takes 67.8 ms and 99.9% of the time is spent in np.einsum, not the reshape. Like hpaulj, I do not think reshape is the issue here. Other operations like denom1 * A_transposed are expensive though.

You are using einsum to do broadcasted outer products.
With a small example:
In [63]: A = np.arange(3); U = np.arange(4*3).reshape(4,3); G=np.arange(5*3).reshape(5,3); Y=np.arange(4*4*3).reshape(4,4,3)

Your numer? calculations time as:
In [64]: %%timeit 
    ...: A_transposed = A[None, :, None].transpose(1, 0, 2)
    ...: numer1 = np.einsum('ai,ak->aik', U.T, G.T).reshape(T, L * K, 1)
    ...: numer2 = numer1 * A_transposed
    ...: numer3 = numer2.sum(axis=0)
    ...: 
    ...: 
37.8 µs ± 74.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

An equivalent with just broadcasting is modestly faster:
In [65]: timeit x=((U[:,None,:]*G[None,:,:]).reshape(-1,3)*A).sum(axis=1)
24.8 µs ± 144 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

They are the same, except for that added trailing dimension:
In [66]: numer3.shape, x.shape
Out[66]: ((20, 1), (20,))

In [67]: np.allclose(x, numer3[:,0])
Out[67]: True

or moving the reshape to the end
In [73]: timeit y=(U[:,None,:]*G[None,:,:]*A).sum(axis=-1).reshape(-1,1)
25.5 µs ± 153 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

edit
In the previous calculation I did two things, replace the einsum with broadcasted multiply, and moved the T dimension to the end, removing the need to the transposing.
In [76]: denom1 = np.einsum('aij,akl->aikjl', Y_transposed, sG).reshape(T, L * K, L *K)
    ...: denom2 = denom1 * A_transposed
    ...: denom3 = denom2.sum(axis=0)

In [77]: Y_transposed.shape, sG.shape
Out[77]: ((3, 4, 4), (3, 5, 5))

In [78]: denom1.shape
Out[78]: (3, 20, 20)

In [79]: Y.shape, G.shape
Out[79]: ((4, 4, 3), (5, 3))

Focusing on moving T/t/a to the end:
In [80]: sg1 = np.einsum('it,jt->ijt', G, G)

Doing broadcasting in [80] will be just as before.
In [82]: denom4 = (np.einsum('ija,kla->ikjla', Y, sg1)*A).sum(axis=-1)

In [83]: denom4.shape
Out[83]: (4, 5, 4, 5)

There are some more dimensions in [82] but the same idea applies.
Now do the reshape and check for equality:
In [84]: denom3.shape
Out[84]: (20, 20)    
In [85]: denom4 = denom4.reshape(L*K,L*K)    
In [86]: np.allclose(denom3, denom4)
Out[86]: True


as you say, it does not add that much speed, but it simplifies the steps nonetheless

can you actually do the same also for the second piece of code? so far my guess (incorrect) is  ((Y_transposed[:, :, :, None, None]*sG[:, None, None, :, :]).reshape(-1,T)*A).sum(axis=1).reshape(K*L, K*L)

I commented on the sG calculation.  You didn't use y_transpose so I skipped that in my testing.

I am actually using Y_transpose in denom1

edited to explore the denio calculations

very nice! this saves some time thanks to avoiding a few reshape and transposed, and ends up in a very neat code. was looking exactly for something like this


It turns out that np.reshape is very slow in this piece of code. Is there a way to avoid reshaping by using the einsum in a different way since I take sums in the last step?

You could avoid a copy during reshape by using a C contiguous array. If the source array is C contiguous, then reshape can always be done without copying. The einsum documentation explains how to output a C contiguous array:

order{‘C’, ‘F’, ‘A’, ‘K’}, optional
Controls the memory layout of the output. ‘C’ means it should be C contiguous. ‘F’ means it should be Fortran contiguous, ‘A’ means it should be ‘F’ if the inputs are all ‘F’, ‘C’ otherwise. ‘K’ means it should be as close to the layout as the inputs as is possible, including arbitrarily permuted axes. Default is ‘K’.

So I would suggest trying np.einsum('ai,ak->aik', U.T, G.T, order='C').reshape(T, L * K, 1).

In my small tests the order parameter hurts the time a bit.  Also I don't think reshape is hurting the OP as much as he thinks.  It's making a view.

@Nick ODell this is a very nice thing. For now this solution allowed to cut the calculation time considerably! considerably is not in absolute terms, but percentage-wise, it is a significant improvement
